# Avarage block size

Tags: block, blocksize

Has someone calculated the avarage block size (e.g., for a day)?
On blockchain.info there are a few blocks listed with their size, on the top of the page :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [your answer](https://blockchain.info/charts/avg-block-size)!
Blockchain.info provides the average block size.

Answer (score 0):

Take http://webbtc.com/ , copy-paste it to excel and calculate average for last 20 blocks.